# kill -9 not working, But the process is not in Z state or D state

Tags: linux, process, ubuntu-12.04, zabbix

We cannot kill the process using "kill -9". But the process is not in Z state or D state.
Any methods to kill this process without rebooting the server.

```
    # ps aux | grep diskstats
    zabbix    2699  0.0  0.0   3956   300 ?        R    Sep24   0:00 sh -c cat /proc/diskstats | grep xvda | head -1 | awk '{print $11}'
    zabbix   21312  0.0  0.0   3956   308 ?        R    Sep24   0:00 sh -c cat /proc/diskstats | grep xvda | head -1 | awk '{print $12}'
    zabbix   21313  0.0  0.0   3956   300 ?        R    Sep24   0:00 sh -c cat /proc/diskstats | grep xvda | head -1 | awk '{print $12}'
    zabbix   21314  0.0  0.0   3956   300 ?        R    Sep24   0:00 sh -c cat /proc/diskstats | grep xvda | head -1 | awk '{print $12}'
    zabbix   21315  0.0  0.0   3956   304 ?        R    Sep24   0:00 sh -c cat /proc/diskstats | grep xvda | head -1 | awk '{print $12}'
    zabbix   21319  0.0  0.0   3956   308 ?        R    Sep24   0:00 sh -c cat /proc/diskstats | grep xvda | head -1 | awk '{print $10}'
    zabbix   21320  0.0  0.0   3956   300 ?        R    Sep24   0:00 sh -c cat /proc/diskstats | grep xvda | head -1 | awk '{print $10}'
    zabbix   21321  0.0  0.0   3956   300 ?        R    Sep24   0:00 sh -c cat /proc/diskstats | grep xvda | head -1 | awk '{print $10}'
    zabbix   21324  0.0  0.0   3956   304 ?        R    Sep24   0:00 sh -c cat /proc/diskstats | grep xvda | head -1 | awk '{print $7}'
    zabbix   21325  0.0  0.0   3956   296 ?        R    Sep24   0:00 sh -c cat /proc/diskstats | grep xvda | head -1 | awk '{print $7}'
    zabbix   21326  0.0  0.0   3956   296 ?        R    Sep24   0:00 sh -c cat /proc/diskstats | grep xvda | head -1 | awk '{print $7}'
    root     21478  0.0  0.0   7552   864 pts/4    S+   06:15   0:00 grep diskstats
    # kill -9 21312
    # kill -9 21313
    # kill -9 21314
    # ps aux | grep diskstats
    zabbix    2699  0.0  0.0   3956   300 ?        R    Sep24   0:00 sh -c cat /proc/diskstats | grep xvda | head -1 | awk '{print $11}'
    zabbix   21312  0.0  0.0   3956   308 ?        R    Sep24   0:00 sh -c cat /proc/diskstats | grep xvda | head -1 | awk '{print $12}'
    zabbix   21313  0.0  0.0   3956   300 ?        R    Sep24   0:00 sh -c cat /proc/diskstats | grep xvda | head -1 | awk '{print $12}'
    zabbix   21314  0.0  0.0   3956   300 ?        R    Sep24   0:00 sh -c cat /proc/diskstats | grep xvda | head -1 | awk '{print $12}'
    zabbix   21315  0.0  0.0   3956   304 ?        R    Sep24   0:00 sh -c cat /proc/diskstats | grep xvda | head -1 | awk '{print $12}'
    zabbix   21319  0.0  0.0   3956   308 ?        R    Sep24   0:00 sh -c cat /proc/diskstats | grep xvda | head -1 | awk '{print $10}'
    zabbix   21320  0.0  0.0   3956   300 ?        R    Sep24   0:00 sh -c cat /proc/diskstats | grep xvda | head -1 | awk '{print $10}'
    zabbix   21321  0.0  0.0   3956   300 ?        R    Sep24   0:00 sh -c cat /proc/diskstats | grep xvda | head -1 | awk '{print $10}'
    zabbix   21324  0.0  0.0   3956   304 ?        R    Sep24   0:00 sh -c cat /proc/diskstats | grep xvda | head -1 | awk '{print $7}'
    zabbix   21325  0.0  0.0   3956   296 ?        R    Sep24   0:00 sh -c cat /proc/diskstats | grep xvda | head -1 | awk '{print $7}'
    zabbix   21326  0.0  0.0   3956   296 ?        R    Sep24   0:00 sh -c cat /proc/diskstats | grep xvda | head -1 | awk '{print $7}'
    root     21648  0.0  0.0   7552   864 pts/4    S+   06:17   0:00 grep diskstats
```

Comment: Please ask on "Unix & Linux Questions". (BTW make sure you are logged in as root or user zabbix.)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this will work as expected. And that "cat" is probably waiting for input blocking the shell or similar. Try to `kill -2` (ctrl-c) the processes. Then rewrite the scripts. I assume these come from `UserParam`, where you can just write:

```
UserParam=whatever.key,/bin/cat /proc/diskstats | grep xvda | head -1 | awk '{print $7}'
```

without `sh -c`.

If this is not the case, I would look at `strace` and `lsof` outputs for the processes in question.